# Issue with toggling status bar color on Android O

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-theme, android-8.0-oreo

Something is not working; I don’t know if it's a problem with the emulator or it's a bug on Android Oreo (I have not a physical device with Android O), but I can’t switch from dark to light status bar theme like in Marshmallow.

styles.xml (from api 23):

```
<resources>

    <style name="ThemeLight" parent="MyBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ThemeDark" parent="MyBaseThemeDark">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

This works fine on Android M, when I change the theme with `setTheme()`, but in Android O, once I switch to the light theme, it is no longer changed and the status bar remains dark (windowLightStatusBar = true) /:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be a bug and I have reported it to google (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65883460).

I use these code to temporary solve the problem.

```
// fix windowLightStatusBar not changed after applyStyle on Android O
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    final TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{android.R.attr.windowLightStatusBar});
    final boolean windowLightStatusBar = a.getBoolean(0, false);
    a.recycle();
    int flag = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    if (windowLightStatusBar) {
        flag |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR;
    } else {
        flag &= ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR;
    }
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flag);
}
```

Comment: this workaround works for me; also it works for `windowLightNavigationBar` in the same way. note that if you are using `applyDayNight()`, it, too, recreates the activity, so the code this solution mentions should still go to your `onCreate()` method.